# Jquery slider not working my webpage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-widget

**Jquery Slider Not Working My Webpage**

My *`HTML`* Code is

```
<div id="sl"></div>
```

My *`Jquery`* Code is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sl" ).slider(); });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/hKc92/

Comment: @Haroon - adeneo can do it...

Comment: Yes we can! What exactly should a slider contain ?

Comment: ***Buy stronger glasses***, it's in the first comment !

Comment: Adeneo can you tell him about the shop for stringer glasses :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Demo its working Man..

```
$(function() {

   $( "#sl" ).slider(); 

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hjEnM/)

There is slider and its working.. Is there anything else you want..?

Comment: Hey...finally you can too.. :)